# Make compiling error 'No rule to make target' when trying to install a driver

Tags: 13.04, drivers, compiling, make, makefile

When I try to install a driver via `sudo make` I get these errors:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-31-generic/build M=
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-31-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-31-generic/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by `arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [archheaders] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-31-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

here is the make file:

```
ifndef KERNELDIR
KERNELDIR  := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
endif

obj-m := ueagle-atm.o
obj-m += usbatm.o

all:
$(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD)

debug:
$(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) EXTRA_CFLAGS="-DDEBUG"

clean:
$(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) clean

install:
$(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules_install
/sbin/depmod -ae
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?
I am having similar problem.. Plz help